# Same Linux Drivers on Different Chips

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am newbie on linux driver development. I wonder how same linux drivers work on different chips. For instance, same uart driver work on allwinner and sitara socs?Do allwinner and sitara socs have same uart peripheral?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically how things are working is based on layering concept as shown below in Image.

Kernel source is layered so that we don't have to write it again and again for every system and to increase its re usability.

Approach behind this is, architect depended code on bottom layer, then comes layer of bus drivers (SPI, I2C, etc.) and then comes adapter or device drivers.

So suppose if a board is using company A's NAND Flash over SPI or any similar interface, we can use same device driver for this company A - NAND Flash on any given board, irrespective of whatever SPI apapter present, but only thing need to be concerned is SPI bus driver should be present as platform driver.

Here while probing, SPI will give access to the device driver with NAND Flash's Address. Here SPI driver knows how to communicate with SPI devices and NAND Flash driver keep on telling to SPI Driver what to transfer to NAND flash and SPI takes responsibility for how to transfer. In this SPI Platform driver may differ with different platforms but NAND Flash driver remains same.

With this approach same device driver for a device can be used in different systems without any dependencies for hardware specification.

[image: Linux Kernel Map]

Comment: Ok. I understand what you wanted to tell about nand driver. But what about spi driver? Because there is one spi driver in the kernel but it works on different platforms.

Comment: NAND driver can be reused, and is independent of the board, but same SPI driver may or may not be reused, even if same SPI adapter is used in different board, chances are memory mapping for SPI adapter may or may not be same. So driver can be re utilized, with just some changes of addresses as per memory mapping of the board.

Comment: There are bunch of SPI driver supporting different adapter in linux kernel source and a single core driver which help the driver to become platform driver. Out of bunch of SPI driver which driver need to used for our board, that we have to configure it while 'make menuconfig' and through device tree.

Answer (score 1):

Well, at first, it doesn't matter what SoC is, or who is the vendor. What matters is the UART peripheral only. So if the peripheral has got some registers on SoC A and exact same registers on SoC B, both of them can go with the same driver. The driver would just tell the underlying bus ( which is usually managed by a different subsystem) to write some configuration bits to specified registers for different operations.
Also, usually if a chip is derived from some old model, simple peripherals like UART remain pretty much the same.

Next .. If all the Allwiner SoCs has the same UART ? Not sure about all of them but this here [ https://github.com/allwinner-zh/linux-3.4-sunxi/blob/master/drivers/tty/serial/Kconfig ] suggests that most of the SoCs use the same UARTs.

And about Sitara Soc, they have shifted to 8250 driver [http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Sitara_Linux_UART_-_Switching_to_8250_Driver], which has been used for many years now. So yeah, since its they (TI) who have decided to this, they will have to maintain backward compatibility in terms of UART.